# How custom a fields of a custom gateway Woocommerce in checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, gateway

I'm building a custom gateway like paypal extended with class `WC_Payment_Gateway` and all is fine!
The problem comes when a user want to validate the order i checkout page.
With PayPal, the data like `?billing_name=foo&customer=minde...`
Now I dont know how send it like do the paypal's custom gateway woocommerce...

Can you tell me how do?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Can you rephrase, provide examples, show code, etc.

Comment: I use the same code that paypal gateway use `woocommerce/includes/gateways/paypal/`. these files explicitly: `class-wp-gateway-paypal.php` and `class-wp-gateway-paypal-request.php` but I have juste edit some params.

Comment: Modify on function `get_paypal_args($order)` line 57 in `class_wp_gateway_paypal_request.php` I add my custom parameters like `        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_paypal_args', array_merge(
            array(
                'custom_field1'           => 'value1',
                'custom_field2'      => 'value2',
                'custom_field3'       => 'value3',
                'custom_field4' => 'value4') `, $this->get_shipping_args)`

Comment: If you just need to change the PayPal args why not filter `woocommerce_paypal_args` instead of duplicating the entire plugin?

Comment: Good idea... I am beginner in the wordpress dev... how can a I do it ? caused I saw the second argumet of filter calling `array_merge()`. And I want to filter too redirect url for a custom url that I would define... (Sorry for my english. I speak french)

Comment: I dont think that it'll be a good idea beceause do it will merge my custom gateway with paypal. or I want paypal too